# Slowly speed up audio track

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

Does anyone know of a tool that will slowly speed up an audio track - normal speed at the beginning and faster at the end with a smooth transition.

I have thought of ffmpeg but I have to idea how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Audacity has [Sliding Stretch tool](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/sliding_stretch.html) for the purpose.

[image]

Comment: thank you so much. how can i set beyond 110%?

Comment: Previous from Audacity forums was old info, updated with what the actual manual says.